# Magento 1.9.2.X Gift Options for Individual Items Bug (Doesn't capture data in checkout)

Tags: magento-1.9

I don't know if anybody is using this or anyone encountered this already, but the gift options for individual items doesn't capture the data entered in the message box upon checkout. For example, if you have more than 1 items and you would like to enter individual messages for those items.

At first, I thought it's just a bug with the IWD OPC extension. But I also tested it in a newly installed Magento 1.9.2.4 without any extension, bought items in my own store, then added separate gift messages for those two items, after checkout, the gift options message field in the admin is blank. There are no additional rows for other gift messages.

Did anyone encounter this before and how did you guys fix it? What I did is I tried other older versions of Magento, and still, it didn't work. So I think it's a bug that wasn't noticed by everyone, because this feature is seldomly used.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops. My mistake. I just found it under "Items Ordered" gift options link per item. So it's linked per item, not inside the gift options block.